# Securing MVC & WebAPI controllers with WsFederation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I have a .NET MVC & WebAPI application that uses `WsFederation` for authentication.  The authentication process is started immediately when users hit the home index route (it's an internal web app).  This works fine.  However, the index page isn't itself a SPA, it's just a series of links to other apps within the solution, so each link is represented by its own MVC controller, which bootstraps its own SPA.

Now, I'd like to get the `ClaimsIdentity` of the current user hitting a WebAPI endpoint, so I'd like to be able to pass a bearer token along with the request.  My problem is that the `UseWsFederationAuthentication` middleware doesn't produce a bearer token, only a cookie.  Ideally, I'd like to generate a bearer token and store it as a claim, and then pass then token to the SPA from the MVC controller.

Is there a way that I can create both a cookie and a bearer token (for MVC & API respectively) at the same time?  I'd like to pass the bearer token to the SPA from the respective MVC controller when the user selects that specific app from the home view.

Apologies if this has been covered before, but any results I find either aren't answered or are a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have several apps in the same solution - but are they in the same URL/domain?

If the answer is *yes* than you do not need to do anything other than your SPA calling your Web APIs and handle eventual HTTP 302 requests coming from your server/ middleware.